# Get user's currency in Odoo 8 (API V7)

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, erp

I need to format a report with the currency of the company's user in Odoo 8.for that I have to get the currency (res.currency) of the current company.

How could I have this data using the old api (API V7).

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share your code, please

Comment: Hi  @CZoellner   I know it in the API V8 and I wanted to know how to code it in APIV7, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid).company_id.currency_id.id
```